# Bluehost using rails 4 error: Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, .htaccess, bluehost

I am using rails 4 on blue-host, every thing goes fine during the installation.

here's output from my shared machine:

```
# ruby --version && rails --version && rake --version && gem --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
Rails 4.2.4
rake, version 10.4.2
2.4.5.1
```

And rails app start when I run rails s:

```
# rails s
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-09-02 13:02:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-02 13:02:15] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-09-02 13:02:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11143 port=3000
```

And here's my .htaccess and dispatch.fcgi files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"require 'fcgi_handler'
RailsFCGIHandler.process!
```

-

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
#PassengerRuby /home1/myapp/ruby
RailsEnv production
RackBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /home1/user/rails_apps/myapp
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home1/user/ruby/gems
SetEnv GEM_PATH /home1/user/ruby/gems
</IfModule>
```

And I am linking my app public to ~/public_html:

```
public_html -> rails_apps/myapp/public
```

But I got the error `Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` when access my rails app from the browser.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running RVM or something like that when installing gems? It seems that the ruby env running under FCGI is not the same. That would explain ruby not finding the gem. Ruby 2.2.3 is quite new I would be surprised if Bluehost is running that. Try echoing the ruby version in your web app `puts RUBY_VERSION`

Comment: I installed it myself from source, not using rvm.

Comment: my app completely is not accessible when access my domain name in the browser

Comment: I think the right question is, how to make that `FCGI` thing to point to my newly installed ruby versions?